# pyspark read key value pair

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, key-value

I have a space delimeted csv file containing key value pair like below :-

a=1 b="2021-02-21 00:00:12" c=5

I have to read it through pyspark.

I used below command :-

a=spark.read.option("quote",""").option('delimiter',' ').csv(/path/abc.csv)

when I execute above, its creating 4 columns instead of 3, like below :-

a=1| b="2021-02-21| 00:00:12"| c=5

Can anyone help how can I put whole values of b in single column.

NOTE: this is just a sample record.
Actual records multiple k-v pairs and also ordering of columns are not same in every files that we receive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat_ws` to concatenate the two columns and `df.columns[n]` to access the columns by index

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
df = df.select(concat_ws('',df.columns[1],df.columns[2]).alias("b"),"a","c")
```

Comment: this is just a sample record. Actual file contains multiple key-value pairs, so wherever there are spaces between values, all those are in double quotes

Comment: Ah, yes this is because of this part of your code `.option('delimiter',' ')` try to change the delimiter to something else or modify your CSV file

Comment: my question is, unlike we have csv file, and we use quotes and escape parameters to escape spaces within double quotes. Is there any way to handle k-v pair, because my values are enclosed with double quotes wherever it contains spaces

Comment: I did not understand the format of your `CSV` file. can you provide an example? In a normal case `delimiter=','`

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use a regular expression, to separate the columns based on the key value pairs you could read the hole line and use the `F.split` function together with some `F.pivot` magic.

```
(spark.read.text("test.csv")
 .withColumn("line_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
 .withColumn("array", F.split("value",r"( )?[a-z]="))
 .withColumn("keys", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in list("abc")]))
 .select(F.col("line_id"),
         F.arrays_zip(F.slice(F.col("keys"),1,3),
                      F.slice(F.col("array"),2,4)).alias("value"))
 .select(F.col("line_id"),F.explode("value").alias("exploded"))
 .select(F.col("line_id"),
         F.col("exploded").getItem("0").alias("key"), 
         F.col("exploded").getItem("1").alias("val"))
 .groupBy("line_id").pivot("key").agg(F.max("val"))
 .show(10, False))
```

that should result in something like:

```
+-------+---+---------------------+---+
|line_id|a  |b                    |c  |
+-------+---+---------------------+---+
|0      |1  |"2021-02-21 00:00:12"|5  |
|1      |3  |"2021-02-21 00:00:52"|4  |
+-------+---+---------------------+---+
```